# No clutch presure, new master cylinder and slave cylinder, no leaks, no air in the system still loosing presure and clutch

Tags: clutch, hyundai, pressure

Hyandai grand max. We replaced the master and slave cylinder new parts in. No leaks no air in the system still it looses pressure and clutch we have adjusted everything and tried evry possible solution.

Comment: Clutch keeps on dissapearing

Comment: Are you suggesting that it sometimes works?

Comment: What do you mean by "clutch keeps on disappearing?"

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the hose sometimes these can cause problem they swell when pressure is put on them, also check the bleeding procedure some cylinders require special bleeding technique to remove trapped air.

Comment: @SamanthaNel How old is the vehicle? A failed hose will indeed produce the symptoms you report, frequently _without displaying externally any indication of failure_.